# Separate UI for iPhone and iPad in Xamarin.Forms using xaml

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have been working on a Xamarin.Forms application that supports iOS and Android platforms. The UI has been build mostly using XAML in the Forms PCL project. I know it is possible through code using

```
if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS && Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
```

How is it possible to build a new UI for iPad through XAML?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Idiom value `OnIdiom` in xaml:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.ColumnSpacing>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
             Phone="20"
             Tablet="40"/>
 </Grid.ColumnSpacing>
</Grid>
```

With this, you can have different values in the xaml for phones or tablets.

When your design for your page are very different for phone and tablets, you better implement two different pages and navigate to the right one, with the idom-code you post in your question:

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Desktop)
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabletPage());
else
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());
```

Look at [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/bringing-xamarin-forms-apps-to-tablets/) from James Montemagno, which describes your problem exactly.

*Edit: Switching between 2 `ContentView`s based on the idiom can be done in the exact same way:

XAML:

```
<ContentPage x:Name="MyPage"></ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Desktop)
    MyPage.Content = new LargeDisplayContentView();
else
    MyPage.Content = new SmallDisplayContentView();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! Will check and get back.

Comment: @DipankarSutradhar I have used the same methods but used a tablet and phone version of a `ContentView` instead of creating a separate page. The effect is essentially the same.

Comment: @hvaughan3 could you possibly post an full answer with that technique explained, would be useful, thanks

Comment: @WickedW Is there a specific problem you are having with the code I posted? Or what part do you need more info on?

Comment: @hvaughan3 did you post any code? you mentioned a possible nice solution regarding ContentView switching, just wanted to see how you did that is all.

Comment: @WickedW I understand now. See edit. Basically the exact same thing but with a `ContentView`